# Can't Integrate Applovin with Admob mediation in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Trying to add Applovin to Admob mediation in a Unity project.The app already had Admob ads working. I imported the Applovin SDK, and was able to build it without problems. Then I imported the Google Applovin Ads Mediation package. I set the Admob key as instructed in the Android Manifest, but now it won't compile.

When I build I get this error.

"The attribute activity#com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity@configChanges=orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout in :com.applovin.applovin-sdk-9.9.1: collides with another value"

Then it says:

"Attribute activity#com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity@configChanges value=(orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout) from [:applovin-sdk:] AndroidManifest.xml:17:13-91 is also present at [:com.applovin.applovin-sdk-9.9.1:] AndroidManifest.xml:17:13-59 value=(orientation|screenSize).

Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:configChanges"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:15:9-19:50 to override."

I am not sure where they want me to place this. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and the suggestion hasn't resolved the issue.

Comment: Rolling back to Applovin SDK 9.9.1 seems to compile

Comment: Thanks will try that

Comment: The only problem is the ads aren't loading even though everything is implemented correctly. I think this is down to the fact that you always need to use the latest SDK. I still haven't found a solution to the manifest merger issue.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so after 2 days of searching I found the solution - add this to your manifest:

```
<activity
android:name="com.applovin.adview.AppLovinInterstitialActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
tools:replace="android:configChanges"
/>
```

Remember to put the implementation of the SDK to pull in the latest version.